# Как правильно прочитать файл Base64 и отобразить данные - вместо русских букв выходят непонятные символы?

Tags: javascript, node.js

С клиента передается файл Excel на сервер Node.js (express).

Получаю строку:

```
file:"<base64 string>".
```

Вот так я принимаю и считываю файл, используя библиотеку XLSX:

```
let fileStr = file;
  let buffer = Buffer.from(fileStr, "base64");
  const wb = XLSX.read(buffer, { type: "buffer" });
```

Результат wb:

```
  {  "SheetNames": [
            "Sheet1"
        ],
        "Sheets": {
    "Sheet1": {
                "A1": {
                    "t": "s",
                    "v": "ÿ\u000f•|ìò¾4ùóæOÆ/v_õ‰³\u0013üìÞŒÏÖß¯¬þ³·—æOþ?CssÊ¸Óüìõ3\u0013üìõ>4ÿ\u000b"
                }
}
    }
    }
    }
```

В поле `V` значение в ячейке с символы получается. А там должен быть русский текст.

Как это можно исправить?

Пробовала еще так :

```
let fileStr = file.file;
  let buffer = Buffer.from(fileStr, "base64").toString('utf-8');
  const wb = XLSX.read(buffer);
  console.log(wb)
```

Но результат одинаковый.

req.body.file выглядит так:

```
data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,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
```

Comment: я думаю сначало нужно обработать приходящие данные попробуй этот вариант.
`baseToString(string) {
    return decodeURIComponent(atob(string).split('').map(function(c) {
     return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
   }).join(''));
  }`

Comment: Вопросы: 1) можете ли вы прислать на сервер файл как файл? если не можете по поясните причину; 2) покажите как вы кодируете файл на клиентской стороне и покажите как именно отправляете; 3) подключен ли у вас bodyParser и пропущены ли данные через него? покажите как выглядит `req.body` внутри роута

Comment: @nörbörnën  подправила, добавила req.body в самый низ вопроса

Comment: @asfd в роуте обрежьте вначале `data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,` и попробуйте снова. и поотвечайте на другие вопросы, если вам надоели прогулки по граблям

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

```
const XLSX = require('xlsx');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

// аналог вашей переменной fileStr
const dataUrl = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'data'), {encoding: 'utf-8'});

const buf = Buffer.from(dataUrl.split(',')[1], 'base64');

const wb = XLSX.read(buf);

console.log(JSON.stringify(wb.Sheets, null, 2));
```

```json
{
  "Лист1": {
    "!ref": "A1:C1",
    "A1": {
      "t": "n",
      "v": 1,
      "w": "1"
    },
    "B1": {
      "t": "n",
      "v": 2,
      "w": "2"
    },
    "C1": {
      "t": "n",
      "v": 3,
      "w": "3"
    },
    "!margins": {
      "left": 0.7,
      "right": 0.7,
      "top": 0.75,
      "bottom": 0.75,
      "header": 0.3,
      "footer": 0.3
    }
  }
}
```

---

<sub>Описание формата данных ячейки, [Worksheet Cell Object](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#cell-object)</sub>